# retrieving most followed user from a users followers

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a `followers` table which (obviously) contains which users follow who.

What I would like to do is find out all of *User 1*'s followers (`U1F`), find out who they're all following (`U1Ffol`), and then using `U1Ffol`, sum together who `U1F` are following the most collectively. This may not make sense, but I've got a pretty rough idea how to show it in **SQL** (bear in mind I'm a bit of a noob, so apologies because this is clearly invalid code **and isn't what I want to use**).

```sql
/* retrieve user 1's followers */
SELECT follower AS U1F FROM followers WHERE following = 1;
/* retrieve who each of those users is following */
SELECT following AS U1Ffol FROM followers WHERE follower IN U1F;
/* find out who they're all following *collectively* */
SELECT 
  following AS User,
  COUNT(*) as f_count 
FROM U1Ffol 
GROUP BY User 
ORDER BY f_count DESC
```

Here is the table structure:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | follower | following |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        2 |         1 |
|  2 |        5 |         1 |
|  3 |        9 |         1 |
|  4 |        1 |         4 |
|  5 |        1 |         5 |
|  6 |        4 |         1 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

So, in this case, the expected output would be (funnily enough the person who they're following the most, collectively, is *User 1*):

```
+------+---------+
| User | f_count |
+------+---------+
|    1 |       4 |
|    4 |       1 |
|    5 |       1 |
+------+---------+
```

Hopefully this makes a bit more sense.

I've been trying to figure this **SQL** out for the last couple of days, but I'm too new to the language to understand how to implement it properly. Therefore, all help and tips would be appreciated,

Cheers.

Comment: Your last select query will successfully gives the expected output. Where is the problem then?

Comment: As per your table structure, Your last query will give you the result. Tables in fiddle and in question are different. Which table i must consider to answer this question?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b5eda/20 Works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I think you must post your expected result then. Coz your expected result posted here is coming through the above fiddle.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai this is very difficult to explain. Hence why I posted that **mock** SQL query to help people understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: If it is difficult for you to explain, How can you expect from us to give you the correct result? Please give a second thought and just post the expected result, We will try our best to give you possible solution.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai by looking at the mock SQL I provided along with the expected result...

Comment: This result is not helping us more to understand the problem statement. Specially 'who they are following most.`

Answer (score 1):

Is below what you want -

```
SELECT following AS User,
       COUNT(*) as f_count 
FROM (SELECT following
      FROM followers
      WHERE follower IN (SELECT follower
                         FROM followers
                         WHERE following = 1)) t
GROUP BY following 
ORDER BY f_count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your queries, after FROM, you need to put the name of your table containing the columns id | followers | etc

The result of a query is also a table, thats why im reusing these results in the next queries, its called sub queries

```
  /* retrieve user 1's followers */
    SELECT follower AS U1F FROM NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE WHERE following = 1;
    /* retrieve who each of those users is following */
    SELECT following AS U1Ffol FROM NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE WHERE follower IN 
    (SELECT follower AS U1F FROM NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE WHERE following = 1);
    /* find out who they're all following *collectively* */
    SELECT 
      following AS User,
      COUNT(*) as f_count 
    FROM (SELECT following AS U1Ffol FROM NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE WHERE follower IN 
    (SELECT follower AS U1F FROM NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE WHERE following = 1))
    GROUP BY User 
    ORDER BY f_count DESC
```

Comment: Oh um, I don't actually want multiple separate select statements. That was just to give you an idea of what sort of needed to be done. Thanks for making the effort though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sample results seem to be:

```
SELECT following AS User,
       COUNT(*) as f_count 
FROM U1Ffol 
WHERE 1 IN (follower, following)
GROUP BY User ;
```